# Disappearing knockout.js bindings on history.back() when using pjax

Tags: knockout.js, pushstate, pjax

I have a test case here: http://tremby.net/knockouttest/page1.php

I'm using pjax for page transitions. Clicking between page 1 and page 2 on the test case above loads the two pages asynchronously and then replaces the contents of the `#main` element. A browser history state is pushed in the process, so the URL in the location bar is updated and the back button is supposed to get us back where we were.

The list on page 1 is populated with knockout's `foreach` binding and the `List` model I've defined (in the inline script in the head). On `ready` on page 1, an inline script runs `ko.applyBindings` and so the list is populated.

The "add item" button adds an item to the view model, which knockout then adds to the list.

Adding a few items and then going to page 2, then back to page 1, the list is fresh with its initial 3 items, and the add item button still works. This is fine for our use case.

Adding a few items and then going to page 2, but then using the browser's back button to go back to page 1, on the other hand, is where my issue is. The new items are still visible (which is good, and 
vital for our use case when the browser's back button is used), but the "add item" button is now broken. The code to push the new item to the `observableArray` is definitely running, but it seems the bindings have disappeared and so knockout doesn't know to add a new DOM element.

I can't run the `ko.applyBindings` function again on `popstate`, or knockout will now think I want each of the now-existing items to be duplicated for each item in the list, and after that each click to "add item" gives multiple new items.

I have a strong feeling there's something obvious I'm missing, but I can't find anything which looks like it'll help in the documentation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just for my understanding why are you defining your JavaScript at the top of the page instead of after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: The only part which runs before the DOM has loaded is the definition of the `List` class. The other chunks run on the `ready` event, which fires after the DOM is good to go. Does that answer your question?

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/ -- `$(handler)` is an alternative Jquery syntax for `$(document).ready(handler)`

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this behaviour because despite having bound the view-model to the UI, you have not persisted it anywhere that the browser history can access it in order to rebuild the page in the state you expect. This behaviour can also be observed using the browser's built-in `back` and `forward` buttons.  The usual pattern I choose to adopt in solving this problem is as follows;

Firstly, assign `this` into a variable this will save you [hassle later on](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).  The view-model should look something like this now;

```
function List(items) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items)
    self.addItem = function(text) {
        self.items.push(text)
    }
}
```

Now create a computed observable that serialises your view-model's current state.  It's entirely up to you how you choose to implement it.

```
self.toJson = ko.computed(function(){
    /*** Serialise self.items() and return the string ***/
    return myJsonString;
});
```

Next, bind the computed to a hidden input, this will ensure that the view-model is persisted in form data allowing you too rehydrate the view-model later.

```
<input id="serialisedItems" type="hidden" data-bind="value: toJson" value="[1,4,3]" />
```

Finally, rehydrate the view-model on `$.ready()` in this fashion;

```
$(function() {
    var items = $('#serialisedItems').val();
    /*** Deserialise items before passing into the List ***/
    var list = new List(deserialisedItems);
    ko.applyBindings(list);
});
```

I should also point out at this point that the list has been initialised by setting the value attribute of the `<input>`.